# Try and catch with Livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have an app that displays a list of movies. There are several types(action,comedy,trending,etc) and there's also a search functionality.

I'm storing the search results in a variable using switchmap. I'm using try and catch to know what to display.

However, I'm having trouble using the search results variable in the try and catch, specifically the error "Cannot assign to 'value': the setter is public in 'getMovies' "

Below is the viewmodel.

Any help is appreciated.

MoviesListViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.ui

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.example.moviesapp.data.MoviesResults
import com.example.moviesapp.data.remote.MoviesRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

const val DEFAULT_QUERY = " "

//Enum class for network state
enum class MovieApiStatus { LOADING, ERROR, DONE }


@HiltViewModel
class MoviesListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MoviesRepository,
) : ViewModel() {


    private var currentQuery = MutableLiveData(DEFAULT_QUERY)

    private val _moviesAction = MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>()
    val moviesAction: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesAction

    private val _moviesComedy = MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>()
    val moviesComedy: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesComedy

    private val _moviesHorror = MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>()
    val moviesHorror: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesHorror

    private val _moviesRomance = MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>()
    val moviesRomance: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesRomance

    private val _moviesScifi = MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>()
    val moviesScifi: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesScifi

    private val _moviesTrending = MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>()
    val moviesTrending: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesTrending

    private val _networkState = MutableLiveData<MovieApiStatus>()
    val networkState: LiveData<MovieApiStatus> = _networkState

    init {
        getMovies()
    }


    var movies = currentQuery.switchMap { queryString ->
        liveData {
            emit(repository.getSearchResults(queryString))
        }
    }



    fun searchMovies(query: String) {

        currentQuery.value = query

    }

    private fun getMovies() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _networkState.value = MovieApiStatus.LOADING
            try {
                _networkState.value = MovieApiStatus.DONE
                _moviesAction.value = repository.getActionMovies()
                _moviesComedy.value = repository.getComedyMovies()
                _moviesHorror.value = repository.getHorrorMovies()
                _moviesRomance.value = repository.getRomanceMovies()
                _moviesScifi.value = repository.getScifiMovies()
                _moviesTrending.value = repository.getTrendingMovies()



            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _networkState.value = MovieApiStatus.ERROR
                _moviesAction.value = listOf()
                _moviesComedy.value = listOf()
                _moviesHorror.value = listOf()
                _moviesScifi.value = listOf()
                _moviesRomance.value = listOf()
                _moviesTrending.value = listOf()
                movies.value = listOf()


            }

        }

    }


    class MoviesListViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val repository: MoviesRepository) :
        ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MoviesListViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MoviesListViewModel(repository) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")

        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`movies` is of type `LiveData<T>`, since you are using `Transformations.switchMap` ([here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#switchMap(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E)) the documentation). You could use a [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) to emit from two different sources

Comment: So movies would be of type mediatorlivedata?